# Distinguishing two Bernoulli random sources

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sampling, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I have a source of independent Bernoulli random variables, which is either $(X_i)$ or $(Y_i)$ where $\Pr[X_i=1]=p$ and $\Pr[Y_i=1]=q$. I can sample as many values as I'd like, and would like to figure out which source I have.

I'm thinking I should pick some threshold $p\le\gamma\le q$ and sample enough values that $\Pr[\sum_i X_i\le n\gamma]$ and $\Pr[\sum_i Y_i\ge n\gamma]$ are both large, e.g. proven by Chernoff bounds.

I can pick $\gamma=1/2(p+q)$, which seems to work well for most values. However for say $p=1/2$, $q=1$ it seems like I would really want $\gamma=1$ rather than $3/4$. This feels like a well studied problem, so I wonder if there is a well known function of $p$ and $q$ to pick $\gamma$ optimally?

Comment: Yes, this is well studied: it is a textbook example of a likelihood ratio test of two simple hypotheses. Instead of using $(1/2)p + (1/2)q$, with weights in the proportion $1:1$, I believe this indicates you should be using weights in proportion $\sqrt{q(1-q)}\,:\,\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, at least asymptotically for large $n$.  For specific $p$, $q$, and $n$, the optimal weights can vary slightly from those proportions. The problem is slightly more interesting, but with a similar solution, when you specify a general loss function (which depends on the four distinct possible errors that can be made).

Comment: If it's proportional to q(1-q) then it's no longer increasing in q..?

Comment: Why should it be? We're talking about *relative weights* in a weighted average of $p$ and $q$, not the actual threshold $\gamma$. For instance, when $q=1$ the relative weights are $0$ and $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, which would make $\gamma=1$.

Comment: Ah, that way around. This looks like the type of function I was encountering when trying to optimise from Chernoff bounds. Awesome! Can you recommend anywhere I may read more about this type of thing?

Comment: I think you will find some good things by using the terms I gave in my first comment for a search, such as [likelihood ratio test simple hypothesis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=likelihood+ratio+test+simple+hypothesis). The key idea is encapsulated in the [Neyman-Pearson lemma, *q.v.*](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Neyman-Pearson+lemma). I wrote down these weights immediately by supposing the sample distributions of the sums would be approximately Normal: $np$ and $nq$ will be their means and $np(1-p)$ and $nq(1-q)$ their variances.